# merging 2 json results

Tags: json, asp-classic

I have 2 different json resuls parsed with asp extreme plugin; `{ "checkins": { "data": [ ] } }` and `{ "trips": { "data": [ ] } }`.

But this is causing me lots of troubles. Is there a way to have a just one json file even though I get the data from 2 different databases.

So like this; `{ "checkins": { "data": [ ] }, "trips": { "data": [ ] }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is the way,

`Set Dataset = JSON.parse("{ ""checkins"": { ""data"": [] }, ""trips"": { ""data"": [] } }")`

I should have just pushed the data in it

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean different databases or different tables in the same database?  If the latter then this is more of an SQL question than asp or json.  I think what you're looking for is an inner join or a left join query.  I suggest you do a bit of background reading on the concept if this is something new to you.  An inner join query for your second recordset would look like

SELECT Trips.TripsID, Trips.MemberID, Trips.TripFrom, Trips.TripTo, Trips.TripDateStarted, Trips.TripDateEnded, Members.MemberId, Members.Firstname, Members.Lastname from Trips inner join Members on Trips.MemberId = Members.MemberId Where Trips.Trips.ID ... etc

This would save you from having to nest one recordset inside another